# start a rails project with batch file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, batch-file, execute

How can I start a rails project using a batch file?
I didn't see the command `rails s` has a path parameter to do that.
What I need to do is to pass an absolute path to my project and activate it by running this batch file.

thanks.

Comment: Otherwise you can use unix aliases to change dir and start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first move to the project location with `cd` then use `rails server`

Example:

```
cd "\Users\Joe\RoR\MyRailsApp"
rails server
```